# System of Quadratics Forms - when is a solution guaranteed to exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system

Suppose I have a system of $\nu$ quadratic forms,
\begin{align*}
x^T A_1 x &= 0 \\
x^T A_2 x &= 0 \\
&\vdots \\
x^T A_\nu x &= 0,
\end{align*}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\mu}$ and each $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{\mu \times \mu}$. Suppose it's also the case that $x^T x = 1$. Suppose none of the $A_i$ are proportional to the identity matrix.

If the $A_i$ are algebraically independent (e.g., orthonormal with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product), is it the case that there *always* exists a solution to this system if $\mu = \nu+1$? If not, are there any restrictions we can put on the $A_i$ so that there will be a solution?

I have observed this phenomenon computationally in every case I have tried so I am hoping/guessing there is some general theory here but I really have no experience in these areas of mathematics.

Related questions are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542039/solving-a-system-of-generic-quadratic-forms), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882411/simultaneous-vanishing-of-quadratic-forms), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413192/n-1-quadratic-forms-for-n-variables) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060718/how-can-i-guarantee-the-existence-of-a-solution-to-this-quadratic-system-of-equa), although I was hoping for a bit more detail. Some references on this material would also be helpful.

Comment: What happens when $\nu=1$ and $A_1$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: Yeah I will edit to avoid that case.

Comment: That is still not enough, e.g., $A_1=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,3,\dots,\mu)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Ok so is your point that we cant say anything in general? Are there no assumptions we can place on the $A_i$ so that a solution is guaranteed to exist?

Comment: @user10354138 if all the $ A_i $ have indefinite signature is that enough to guarantee a solution?

Comment: @user10354138 Yeah interesting comment that Ian said; is it enough if every matrix has indefinite signature?

Comment: You can still get silly examples such as $A_1=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1),A_2=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-2)$.